# pdo class vs pdostatment class - beginner

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looking for a simple explanation of the difference between the pdo class and the pdostatement class.

For example, if I am accessing values in an instance of a new pdo object like `$newObject = new PDO(connection info);` Then how come I can also make a prepared statement in that same object by doing something like `$newObject->prepare(prepared statement); $newObject->execute(statement);` when those methods are part of the pdostatment object?

I am new to OOP so any simple explanation would really help.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php They are methos of PDO, their return type is PDOStatement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDO class has the connection to the sql-server and returns PDOStatements, either executed or that can be executed later.

PDOStatements can either first be [prepared](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and then [executed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), simply [queried](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) without preparing it (i.e. not binding any data to the statement).

After successfully executing a statement, the result can the be fetched from the PDOStatment with any of the "fetch" methods:

- fetch
- fetchAll

Comment: so the when I take a new pdo object and call the ->prepare method it is really packaging all that up into a pdostatement object that comes back?  I think that make sense.

Comment: Im not 100% about if all connetion information is held inside the PDOStatement, PDOStatement could have a reference to the PDO instance instead, which would make more sense (instead of duplicating the connection info in each PDOStatement).

Answer (score 0):

You could see it like this:

PDO is the connection to your database, PDOStatement is your query.

Assume the following variables:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$statement = $pdo->prepare($statement);
```

`$pdo` is an instance of [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), whilst `$statement` is an instance of [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Now on `$statement` you can call `->execute()` to execute the query.